# Singularity or not

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

A point in which a function is not defined, for instance for $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$ let consider $x=1$, it makes sense to know if it is a point of singularity? Or not since the study of derivability makes sense only in the domain?

Comment: The difficulty about this question is the vagueness of "makes sense". You have tagged the question as "derivatives" and nothing else. If your only interest is the derivatives of real-valued functions defined on a subset of the reals, then there is not much point in thinking about singularities, although you may be interested in points where either the function or its derivative is undefined. If you later become interested in complex analysis, then the fact that $1/(z-1)$ has a simple "pole" at $z=1$ becomes important.

Comment: Yes sorry I am referring to real analysis

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to define what you mean by "[singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics))". People may call a point outside of the domain of a function "singular". Sometimes, a point where the function is not differentiable is also called "singular".

In complex analysis, there are several kinds of "singularities". For instance, near $z=0$, the functions $f(z)=\frac1z$ and  $g(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}$ behave quite differently.

Comment: In case of referring to notion of point in which the function is not differentiable so it does not make sense to question if x=1 in singular or not, right?

Comment: @Nik: Whether a point is "singular" or not depends on what function you are talking about. Without talking about any functions, yes, it does not make sense to ask whether a point is singular.

Comment: @Nik: what one would say is that "some function is singular *at* some point".